# API Version Routing - change code from Express to KOA

Tags: node.js, express, koa

I am trying to create different routes for different API versions.

I saw the following stackoverflow post:
[How do you handle api version in a Node/Express app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26040329/how-do-you-handle-api-version-in-a-node-express-app)

which linked me to this express js code:
http://j-query.blogspot.ca/2013/01/versioned-apis-with-express.html

I am trying to copy the code and convert it to KOA (which I am a bit new to..)

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would seem to work:

```
let koa     = require('koa'),
    router  = require('koa-router'),
    app     = koa();

let v1 = new Router({
  prefix: '/v1'
});

// responds to "/v1"
v1.get('/', ...) 
v1.post('/', ...) 

app.use(v1.routes());
app.use(v1.allowedMethods());

let v2 = new Router({
  prefix: '/v2'
});

// responds to "/v2"
v2.get('/', ...) 
v2.post('/', ...) 

app.use(v2.routes());
app.use(v2.allowedMethods());

app.listen(3000);
```